# How can I see source Code not decompiled code from error stack jump

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea

[image]

Look this picture with red circle,

I can see error stack show real class Name,

So I think Android Studio know the source code,

But I only could jump to see decompiled code.

How can I see the source code ?

this is a third-part lib manage by Gradle.

this is my import config 
`compile 'com.umeng.analytics:analytics:latest.integration'`

Thanks!

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  add this to your android manifest file

Comment: I am saying to add permissions because i found it from your stacktrace that error is due to missing permissions...

Comment: my problem is not no permission, is how can I read real source code but not decompiled code,I ask the question beacuse I found real class name in stacktrace,thanks

Comment: Could you post your real class code..??

Comment: I can't ,I don't have  source  code,

Comment: 's in that case you might be having apk  just try extracting source code from apk tool..